# Crear un ModelBinder para KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, binding

El ModelBinder por defecto de ASP.NET MVC no es capaz de enlazar los datos con variables del tipo KeyValuePair.
Esto es debido a la forma que tiene de enlazar los tipos complejos: en primer lugar crea una nueva instancia del objeto a través de un constructor sin argumentos y a continuación va estableciendo los valores de las diferentes propiedades. En este caso las propiedades Key y Value del objeto KeyValuePair son de sólo lectura, por lo que puede asignarle valores y queda el objeto vacío.

La solución pasaría por crear un ModelBinder personalizado para este tipo pero ¿cómo podría crear un ModelBinder para un tipo genérico como KeyValuePair?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final lo he solucionado así:

He creado un ModelBinder para los tipos de datos KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> que obtiene los valores de las propiedades Key y Value y devuelve el objeto KeyValuePair:

```
public class KeyValuePairModelBinder : IModelBinder
{

    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var values = bindingContext.ValueProvider as ValueProviderCollection;
        if (values == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var key = values.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName + ".Key");
        var keyValue = Convert.ChangeType(key.AttemptedValue, bindingContext.ModelType.GetGenericArguments()[0]);
        var value = values.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName + ".Value");
        var valueValue = Convert.ChangeType(value.AttemptedValue, bindingContext.ModelType.GetGenericArguments()[1]);
        return Activator.CreateInstance(bindingContext.ModelType, keyValue, valueValue);
    }
}
```

Y un ModelBinderProvider que comprueba si el tipo de datos del modelo se corresponde con KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> y, si es así, devuelve una instancia de este ModelBinder:

```
public class KeyValuePairModelBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{

    public IModelBinder GetBinder(Type modelType)
    {
        if (modelType.IsGenericType &&
            modelType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof (KeyValuePair<,>))
        {
            return new KeyValuePairModelBinder();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Luego simplemente hay que añadir el ModelBinderProvider a la colección BinderProviders en el método Application_Start del Global.asax:

```
ModelBinderProviders.BinderProviders.Add(new KeyValuePairModelBinderProvider());
```

Answer (score 2):

Buscando sobre el tema puede analizar esta pregunta similar a lo que planteas

[ASP MVC.NET - how to bind KeyValuePair?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300642/asp-mvc-net-how-to-bind-keyvaluepair)

alli crea un `custom ModelBinder` en donde detecta el tipo de dato del model y si es un `KeyValuePair` selecciona de la coleccion de valores que provienen del request y lo asignas a una instancia usando `Activator.CreateInstance`

Analiza el ejemplo de planteado por `Petr J`

**>>quería mirar la opción de crear un ModelBinderProvider que discrimine qué ModelBinder utilizar para los tipos KeyValuePair**

quizas podrias evaluar

[aspnetwebstack Binders](https://github.com/mono/aspnetwebstack/tree/master/src/System.Web.Http/ModelBinding/Binders)

alli veras dos clases: `KeyValuePairModelBinder.cs` y `KeyValuePairModelBinderProvider.cs`

creo que apuntas a algo como eso

Comment: Sí, estaba pensando en algo similar.
Lo que no me gustaba demasiado de esa solución es que haciéndolo así debería reemplazar el ModelBinder por defecto de la aplicación.
Antes de tirar por ahí quería mirar la opción de crear un ModelBinderProvider que discrimine qué ModelBinder utilizar para los tipos KeyValuePair.

Comment: En cuanto al código del ModelBinder y el ModelBinderProvider sí, esa es la idea.
De hecho esa es la implementación de WebAPI también existe otra implementación para WebForms en el namespace System.Web.ModelBinding, pero no hay una para MVC.

Comment: porque dices que es la implementacion para webapi ? alli veo que esas clases estan sobre System.Web.Http no veo que apliquen solo a ApiController lo veo mas general

Comment: Porque es la implementación que utiliza WebAPI que sí realiza el binding de este tipo de datos por defecto.
La implementación de MVC es diferente.
Por ejemplo las diferentes interfaces IModelBinder definen el mismo método BindModel pero con diferentes firmas:
- WebAPI: bool BindModel( HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext )
- WebForms: bool BindModel( ModelBindingExecutionContext modelBindingExecutionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext )
- MVC: Object BindModel( ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext )

Answer (score -1):

En MVC5 existe el [KeyValuePairModelBinderProvider Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn154697(v=vs.118).aspx)

Saludos

Comment: Sergio, no funciona el link

Comment: Perdona, corregido

Comment: Sí, en el namespace Microsoft.Web.Mvc.ModelBinding. El problema es que ese namespace define clases para realizar binding con controles WebForm. De hecho lo que devuelve el método GetBinder es un IExtensibleModelBinder no un objeto IModelBinder como en MVC